# Referencing OpenWebKitSharp to use WebKit in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I am trying to reference OpenWebKitSharp, the C# library for WebKit.  However, I keep getting an error on compiling: "The type or namespace WebKitBrowser does not exist in the namespace WebKit".
I am trying to follow the directions at http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/ but I do not know what this means:
Copy the contents of the cairo build to your debug/release folder.

What is a cairo build?  Why do I keep getting this error even though I am referencing both WebKit.Interop and OpenWebKitSharp?
On a similar note, is there a good site for documentation about the OpenWebKitSharp library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `.Net Framework Client Profile`, change it to `.Net Framework 4`

Comment: Thank you, this works!  But now I am getting another error on compiling: Could not load file or assembly WebKit.Interop, Version=534.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I think you have to copy `WebKit.Interop.dll` manually to bin/{debug|release} of your project

Comment: @CarlBenson: he are in same exact hell hole.

Comment: This had me stumped for ages. In the properties for the Webkit.Interop reference change "Embeded Interop Type" to false. Worked for me!

Comment: If you are using .Net Framework 4 , change to .Net Framework 4 Client Profile, and change back to .Net Framework 4

Comment: I am trying to add OpenWebkitSharp 3.0.1.0023 in one of my C# projects . I have added all the references and everything is followed to the point as mentioned [here](http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c/99355-combining-webkit-visual-c.html). The problem is when I run the project it gives me an SEHException saying an external component has thrown an exception. I have verified that WebKit.Interop.dll exists in the build folder of my app also have performed a step pointed out by @rashleighp but still I am stuck. Any help would be great. Thanks :-)